# Receiving a TypeError: Required argument 'object' (pos 1) not found

Tags: python, pyautogui, openai-gym

I'm trying to create an gym environment that moves the mouse (in a VM, obviously)... I don't know much about classes, but is there supposed to be an argument for self or something...? Also, any improvements would be greatly appreciated...

This code is basically going to run on a VM, soo...I've tried to remove the line of code, but there's several lines that don't run... (I'm terrible at explaining things)

Here's the code:

```
class MouseEnv(Env):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ACC = 0
        self.reward = 0
        self.done = False
        self.reset()

    def step(self, action):
        try:
            self.action = action
            done = False

            if self.action == 1:
                pyautogui.click()
                self.reward += 0.2
            else:
                if self.ACC == 1:
                    self.action = min((self.action/100), 1) * 1920
                    self.prev_action = min((self.prev_action/100), 1) * 1080
                    self.reward += 0.4

                else:
                    self.ACC = 1
                    self.prev_action = self.action()
                    self.reset()
            screen = ImageGrab.grab()
            self.observation = np.array(screen)
        except:
            done = True
        return self.observation, self.reward, done, {}           
    def reset(self):
        self.observation = np.array()
        self.reward = 0
        self.done = 0
        return self.observation
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rees/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 171, in make
    return registry.make(id, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rees/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 123, in make
    env = spec.make(**kwargs)
  File "/home/rees/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 87, in make
    env = cls(**_kwargs)
  File "/home/rees/Desktop/gym-mouse/MouseGym/envs/mouse_env.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.reset()
  File "/home/rees/Desktop/gym-mouse/MouseGym/envs/mouse_env.py", line 41, in reset
    self.observation = np.array()
TypeError: Required argument 'object' (pos 1) not found
```

Expected Result:

I expect the mouse to move based on the agent's input/actions, and the observation to be a live video feed of the screen...

Comment: The traceback quotes the line : `self.observation = np.array()`, but the same line in your code is `self.observation = np.array(screen)`. Did you copy your code correctly?

Comment: Okay, I tried rebuilding my module using pip install -e . in the gym-mouse directory... Same error when I try to make the gym environment using gym.make...

Comment: There's a reset function towards the bottom of my code also...

Comment: It would be useful to have the code for `reset` as well, given: `File ... line 41, in reset` indicates that's where the error is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that in your `reset` function, when you try to initialize `self.observation` with an empty numpy array, you do not pass any arguments to `np.array()`. You have two options here, pass an empty list to the function:

```
self.observation = np.array([])
```

or use `np.empty`, which will create an empty numpy array:

```
self.observation = np.empty(0)
```